# Docker compose port forwarding Linux asp.net core

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, yaml, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a couple of docker images, they run fine apart from the ports are always 5000 (the default, on asp.net core), no matter what I do they are not changing, any ideas, how to fix or debug this further?

**Containers running on Linux (Debian 9)**
Hosted on Linode

**Starting the build with**

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
#Api  Service
API:
 build:
  context: .
  #Use the DockerFile in that Directory
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  #This Service Depends on the database service specifed above
  depends_on:
  - database
#Map port 8888 in the docker container to port 80 in the Api
ports:
  - "5000:80"
restart: always
#Specify Environment Variables for the Api Service
environment:
  - DBHOST=database
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
```

**DockerFile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80/tcp

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestApi.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "TestApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish


FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApi.dll"]
```

**docker-compose.debug.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  testapi:
    image: testapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80
      - 5000
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

Comment: but there is `- "5000:80"`

Comment: Hi @RomanMarusyk , yeah pretty much all the examples are that way round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, ASP.NET Core apps run on port 5000 (or 5001 for TLS).  You can change this in a few ways, the easiest being to set the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable, e.g. if you want to run on the more typical HTTP/S ports 80/443:

```
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
```

That said, I don't see any reason you would want to do this.  Why don't you just bind to port 5000 on your container?  E.g. instead of `5000:80` use `5000:5000`.  Might be worth reading the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time to answer , I have added docker-compose.debug.yml which does contain the environment port 80, that being said is it worth adding direct in the docker-compose.yml file ?

Comment: Thanks for adding that file, looks better.  If you want to use port 80 then I would recommend putting `ASPNETCORE_URLS` in your `Dockerfile` actually, e.g. `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80`.  But personally I would use the standard port 5000 because your environments will be more consistent and because less is more with configuration.

Comment: HI, yup im gonna stick with pot 5k, i need to test it works on port80 and setup a letsencrpyt cert , I;ll test and come back, thanks